# Focus losing from grid's last blank row to second last row when the activation of another form

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub grdDayBook_KeyDown(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles grdDayBook.KeyDown
    If CurrentColumn = 1 Then
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then
            'e.SuppressKeyPress = False
            FrmAccountsSearch.Text = "From Daybook"
            FrmAccountsSearch.Show()
            FrmAccountsSearch.Activate()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

As per the above code, when I press "F5" in the 1st column, last blank row of a grid, a second form will be activated.  But the problem is.. after the activation of the second form, its losing the focus from the last row to one step up (second last row) and also focus is going to another control.  I have wrote in the load event of the second form `Me.MdiParent = FrmMain`.  If I removed this code (`Me.MdiParent = FrmMain`), its working perfectly.  I mean the focus will not be change to anywhere.  But I should include this code.  What I should do masters?

Comment: Firstly, why do you have the child form setting its own parent instead of the parent setting it?

Comment: When you make a form an MDI child, it actually becomes a child control on the parent form.  As such, it is going to take focus from whatever control previously had it. When that form is closed, presumably the next control in the Tab order will receive focus.

Comment: Sir, I dnt understand ur first comment.  Can u pls describe it?

Comment: You're setting the `MdiParent` property of the child form in the child form.  You should be doing it in the parent form.

Comment: I wrote `FrmAccountsSearch.MdiParent = FrmMain` before the code `FrmAccountsSearch.Show()` But I am getting same result.

Comment: I wasn't saying that that would fix your issue, just that it's the proper way to write the code. My second comment addressed your issue, i.e. it is normal behaviour and not a bug.